# How to find position in rigid body dynamics simulation using Kinetic Energy

Tags: math, simulation, physics, discrete-mathematics, rigid-bodies

I am trying to implement rigid bodies dynamics for my simulation. I am trying to simulate a tensegrity as in the paper attached.

The paper I follow is: [Dynamic equations of motion for a 3-bar tensegrity based mobile robot](http://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/30336/1/Dynamic%20equations.pdf)

According to this paper and what I have read so far the general process is:

**For each bar:**

- A) define the bar’s pose (q) : for that I need a position vector and an 
  orientation vector. I have this since it is my initial position.
- B) Apply initial velocity: which is 0
- C) Find Kinetic Energy
- D) Find Potential Energy
- E) Find Torque

**For the total system:**

- A) Find Kinetic Energy
- B) Find Potential Energy
- C) Find Torque

My question is how can I find the new pose (**position and orientation**) of each bar according to **Kinetic Energy**, **Potential Energy** and **Torque**?

As I understand, I will need the linear acceleration and angular acceleration, and then the linear velocity and angular velocity and finally update pose (position and orientation). I don’t understand how could I do this.

I looked at those books and read some notes, but I didn't understand practically how to do this

1. Rigid Body Dynamics Algorithms, by Roy Featherstone
2. Physics for Game Developers, David M.Bourg
3. Physically Based Modeling, David Baraff

   ---

**Extra Clarification if possible:**

1) Basically the `W` matrix that requires the angles of `φ, θ,` would those angles be the angles of the basic reference frame for the whole structure? Not the angles for each bar, because this is not [image: φι], I assume it is for the whole system?

2) Regarding the Inertia matrix of the mobile reference frame, I understand this must refer for each bar? But since [image: dM/dq] is for the whole system, what should be the matrix of  [image: Imb]?

3) How to factorize `M(q)`

4) In the paper, it is described through [image: uCo]in the cables. I would like to try something else, the bars connected together in the center and each one would be possible to move axially only.  So I guess I will have to add a force for each bar and affect this?

If you have any information could you please let me know?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have much time right now I'll elaborate later. Quickly on your clarifications: 3) since you can factorize each diagonal block separately you can use a direct method, try LU or QR decompositions. 1) and 2), each W is for a different bar, and the general form is expressed in terms of 2 angles φ, θ which you should in turn express in terms of the angles in `si` (a drawing would help I guess). `ϕi` will likely be useless since it's the longitudinal rotation of the bar. I<sub>MB</sub> is given by relation (4), and I<sub>FB</sub> = W<sup>T</sup>I<sub>MB</sub>W

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask in 4) bu let's first solve the initial problem, then only change it.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is equation 12 in your paper, which gives you the acceleration at time t.

## Computing acceleration

If you look carefully at equation 12, every term is previously defined (except maybe the gravitational forces which are `-g * mi` along the z axis for each node `i`, thus `f gi = [0, 0, -g * mi]`). I recommend that you start building/computing each of these terms (taking into account the remarks on changing basis for `I`).

To differentiate `M(q)`, remember that all of the `mi`, `li`, `r1i` and `r2i` are constant, thus only the `W` have a non-zero derivative:

[image: differentiating M over q]

Then just differentiate each term inside the

Only the unknown will remain, which is the acceleration, written in the paper as  [image: q with 2 dots on top]

You now need to put all the elements that you have computed on the right hand side of the equation, compute the resulting vector, and factorize your `M(q)`, which is the block-diagonal matrix of all the `Mi(q)`, thus this is equivalent to factorizing each `Mi(q)`. Then you will have the acceleration, from which you can integrate velocity, and in turn, position.

## Integrating

This is left out of the paper, but isn't too hard. Since you need velocities to compute acceleration, you will have to use a first order integrator like the [Semi-Implicit Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-implicit_Euler_method) for example.

Thus the velocity and position should be updated as follows:

[image: simple first-order integration]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that was really helpful! I have implemented and coded most of the process and I am trying to understand some parts in more detail. I have added those on the question.

Comment: To clarify more what I explained above in what I am interested in doing. Basically, I would like to have bars that their center of mass is at the same position with the others but have different orientation. The reference frame of the whole system is set to in the same position as the center. The dynamics of the bars should be that after applying force to any of the bars, this will move linearly in its axis.

Comment: However their orientation in bar’s reference frame will not change. Any movement in any of the bars along with the external forces (i.e. gravity), affects the system’s reference frame (in rotating or changing its position). If have any reference for reading regarding this or any suggestions on how can I inform my code, please let me know. Thank you again for your answer, really helpful!